# generate cartesian product of boolean parameter values

Tags: python

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self, a=False, b=False, c=False, d=False):
        ...
```

I need to generate all instances of Config with different values for a, b, c, d. They can be True or False. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
[Config(*x) for x in itertools.product([False, True], repeat=4)]
```

(Note that these are not permutations.)

Comment: Nice answer.  Generating all possible test inputs is a principal use case for *itertools.product*.